# Border gradient disapear when import bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, linear-gradients

I have made an full width animated gradient border, but when i want to make 2 row in the middle with bootstrap, when i have imported the bootstrap cdn css the gradient disappear

I've take 2 screenshots before and after.

Thank u.

[Before import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPSIb.png)

[After import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYrSq.png)

Comment: _“look at the images below”_ - please _look at_ (i.e., _read_) [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @EvroHQ you need to share some code for others to figure out what you are doing and if it's right or wrong. Or else how will others figure out your approach?

Comment: Probably bootstrap override some of your styles.

Comment: @TomaszKisiel yes it was that, i've rename my className and it work. thanks man!